# Implement parameter validation through Proxy, InvocationHandler and custom Annotations

Tags: java, spring, reflection, proxy

I am trying to imitate Spings validated and custom constraints annotations so that I can validate parameters when they reach an endpoint on my server. I got the basics of Proxy and InvocationHandler down, but I am stuck on how a single annotation would execute some code. Take this example:

I  want parameters annotated with

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface PostId {}
```

to be validated automatically in the background. So ideally for any method with a parameter and this annotation I could create validation tests.

```
public class Main {

    public void doSomething(@PostId String id) {
        // id should be evaluated in the background and not explicitly
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "test";
        doSomething(test);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I explicitly said I want to imitate the behavior of Spring because I want to implement this myself, but I don't quite know how to.

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` only works with interfaces - so you have to call your methods through an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations do not mean anything by themselves (in most cases): they should be *processed/handled* **somewhere** else, and, as you correctly noted, there *could be* a hidden `Proxy`.

> I want to imitate the behavior of Spring because I want to implement this myself, but I don't quite know how to.

Let's introduce some minimal example without Spring, using only pure jdk facilities:

Imagine we have some **`interface`** (currently in JDK we cannot easily subclass a class, but we can create a class implementing some `interface`s):

```java
public interface PostService {
    Post getPostById(@PostId long id);
}
```

And a simple implementation:

```java
public class SimplePostService implements PostService {
    @Override
    public Post getPostById(@PostId long id) {
        return new Post(id);
    }
}
```

Now, let's perform validation: we will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if an `id` passed is negative

To do so we use can jdk's [Dynamic Proxy Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). The interesting part is the [`Proxy#newProxyInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)) method:

- It accepts:

  - `ClassLoader`
  - array of `interface`s that a target class will `implement`
  - `InvocationHandler` - it's where we can be embed any logic

```java
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Target, real service
        SimplePostService targetPostService = new SimplePostService();

        PostService proxiedService = (PostService) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Main.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{PostService.class}, (proxy, method, methodArguments) -> {
            Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
            // iterate over all arguments
            for (int i = 0; i < methodArguments.length; i++) {
                PostId annotation = parameters[i].getAnnotation(PostId.class);
                // if annotation is present
                if (annotation != null) {
                    long id = ((long) methodArguments[i]);
                    // And argument is not valid
                    if (id < 0) {
                        // then throw
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative id = " + id);
                    }
                }
            }
            // else invoke target service
            return method.invoke(targetPostService, methodArguments);
        });

        System.out.println(proxiedService.getPostById(-1));
    }
}
```

The code above:

- Creates a target, real service (`SimplePostService`)
- Creates a proxy class, that `implements PostService`
- Intercepts invocations to proxy:

  - It iterates over arguments and if it's *not valid* (negative in the example above), it throws `IllegalArgumentException`
  - Otherwise, it invokes target, real service

The code above should demonstrate the basic principle how Spring performs its `@Valid`/`@Transactional`/`@Cacheable` handling. Sure, it uses more sophisticated approach:

- It can create subclasses dynamically (not only create instances of classes that `implement` some interface`)
- It provides a framework to make it easier to implement this kind of logic, see [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @Denis! I think I understand your example with the proxy instance creation. So basically to arrive at Spring-like functionality I would have to somehow encapsulate the method call of my endpoint in a proxy that extends an interface, so that I can "inject" code before and after executing the actual method? My professor said it would be useful to do it once by yourself, just to what spring does in the background. But doing my own implementation on-top of Spring seems counterproductive.

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, it boils down to injecting some code before/after actual method invocation. Validation is a little bit subtle, because in Spring MVC the framework can validate arguments [without using a proxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java#L137).

Comment: I'd rather suggest to take a look at [`CacheInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor.java). Either way, the basic example in the answer should help to understand the underlying mechanism